# Calculations for a square matrix using PHP

Tags: php, math, matrix

I am a postgraduate student and I have small knowledge of PHP and SQL.
I have an square matrix of about 12x12 and I take the data to fill it from an database.
My problem is that I need to get all the posible combinations adding one value from each row and PHP takes more than 15 minutes to do it.

What I do, after obtaining the data from the database, is introduce them in 12 arrays, one per each row with 12 values each one, one per each column of the matrix.
After that, I basically go into 12 loops, one per each array to add each value with each value of every row.
My arrays are from $d0 to $d11

```
for ($id0=0; $id0<=11; ++$id0){
$v0=$d0[$id0];
for ($id1=0; $id1<=11; ++$id1){
    if ($id1 <> $id0){
        $v1=$v0+$d1[$id1];

        for ($id2=0; $id2<=11; ++$id2){
        if (($id2 <> $id1)&&($id2 <> $id0)) {
            $v2=$v1+$d2[$id2];

            for ($id3=0; $id3<=11; ++$id3){
            if (($id3 <> $id0) && ($id3 <> $id1) && ($id3 <> $id2)) {
                $v3=$v2+$d3[$id3];

                for ($id4=0; $id4<=11; ++$id4){
                if (($id4 <> $id0) && ($id4 <> $id1) && ($id4 <> $id2) && ($id4 <> $id3)) {
                    $v4=$v3+$d4[$id4];

                    for ($id5=0; $id5<=11; ++$id5){
                    if (($id5 <> $id0) && ($id5 <> $id1) && ($id5 <> $id2) && ($id5 <> $id3) && ($id5 <> $id4)) {
                        $v5=$v4+$d5[$id5];

                        for ($id6=0; $id6<=11; ++$id6){
                        if (($id6 <> $id0) && ($id6 <> $id1) && ($id6 <> $id2) && ($id6 <> $id3) &&  ($id6 <> $id4) && ($id6 <> $id5)) {
                            $v6=$v5+$d6[$id6];

                            for ($id7=0; $id7<=11; ++$id7){
                            if (($id7 <> $id0) && ($id7 <> $id1) && ($id7 <> $id2) && ($id7 <> $id3) &&  ($id7 <> $id4) && ($id7 <> $id5) && ($id7 <> $id6)) {
                                $v7=$v6+$d7[$id7];

                                for ($id8=0; $id8<=11; ++$id8){
                                if (($id8 <> $id0) && ($id8 <> $id1) && ($id8 <> $id2) && ($id8 <> $id3) &&  ($id8 <> $id4) && ($id8 <> $id5) && ($id8 <> $id6)  && ($id8 <> $id7)) {
                                    $v8=$v7+$d8[$id8];

                                    for ($id9=0; $id9<=11; ++$id9){
                                    if  (($id9 <> $id1) && ($id9 <> $id2) && ($id9 <> $id3) &&  ($id9 <> $id4) && ($id9 <> $id5) && ($id9 <> $id6) && ($id9 <> $id7)  && ($id9 <> $id8) && ($id9 <> $id0)  ) {
                                        $v9=$v8+$d9[$id9];  

                                        for ($id10=0; $id10<=11; ++$id10){
                                        if  (($id10 <> $id1) && ($id10 <> $id2) && ($id10 <> $id3) &&  ($id10 <> $id4) && ($id10 <> $id5) && ($id10 <> $id6) && ($id10 <> $id7)  && ($id10 <> $id8) && ($id10 <> $id0)  && ($id10 <> $id9) ) {

                                            $v10=$v9+$d10[$id10];   

                                            for ($id11=0; $id11<=11; ++$id11){
                                            if  (($id11 <> $id0)  && ($id11 <> $id1) && ($id11 <> $id2) && ($id11 <> $id3) &&  ($id11 <> $id4) && ($id11 <> $id5) && ($id11 <> $id6) && ($id11 <> $id7)  &&  ($id11 <> $id8) && ($id11 <> $id9) && ($id11 <> $id10) ) {

                                                $v11=$v10+$d11[$id11];  

                                                if ($v11<$best){
                                                    $consumers = $id0.$id1.$id2.$id3.$id4.$id5.$id6.$id7.$id8.$id9.$id10.$id11;
                                                    $best = $v11;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }

        }
        }
    }
    }
}
echo $consumers;
echo "</br>";
echo $best;
```

Could you know please another way to do it and get results faster? The performance is very slow and it takes about 15 minutes on giving me the result.
How could I improve the performance?

Sorry to ask here for such a massive help but I dont have too much money to get a mathematician to fix it and I would like to solve it as it would be a big improvement on finishing my PhD.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You're running 12^12 iterations, which is about 9 trillion. No matter what you do, that much math is going to take a while. This isn't helped by the fact that you're doing this in PHP.

Comment: Are you trying to find the indices that give you the smallest sum? If so, why aren't you just finding the smallest entry in each set, then summing those? As far as I can tell you're brute forcing every possible sum of elements from each set, and finding the minimum of that. This requires trillions of comparisons instead hundreds.

Comment: If anything, I'm surprised that this only takes 15 minutes.

Comment: +1 to everything @ThomasJager said. We definitely need a better idea of what your code is supposed to accomplish. At a glance I would suggest two things that probably apply: 1. Divide and Conquer: Split the problem into smaller independent subproblems, solve those, and combine the results. eg: solving each 3x3 submatrix might be faster than trying to solve the whole thing at one. 2. Recursion: If you need to delve into a data structure of arbitrary depth, recursion is usually the way to go. Also a good way to solve subproblems from the inside out.

Comment: Now that I look at it, is this a pathfinding problem? If so, there are a number of algorithms that could be applied. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding

Comment: One more pass over and it looks like you're just looking for the smallest possible combination of one element from each array, which is just the sum of the smallest elements of each array. So just pick the smallest item out of each array directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answers.
The matrix is related to buyers preference related to distance and the matrix has a term that has made me imposible to apply anything related to Dijkstra:
Each row can only related to one column and viceversa so if the first column takes the value in the 5th column, no other row can take a value in the fifth colum and the first row will have no more relations. 
This is why also it is not working taking the lower value from each row is working.
Again thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @kautik I want to note that your current code does not appear to follow what you say. It finds the smallest, with overlaps. Your chosen route could come completely from the first column. However, you should add what you're trying to do to the question, because you're not currently doing what you want to.

Comment: My proposed solution would be to use recursion to pick the smallest number in each row to start, then passing the unused rows recursively. The function itself would iterate through the passed arrays. That should get you down to O(n!) instead of O(n^n). I've never done much comp sci, but I'm pretty sure it's unusual for O(n!) to be an improvement. It will however get you down to 500 million iterations instead of 9 trillion, and should complete almost instantly, compared to the original. If I have the time, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: It might actually be O(n*n!), but that's still better than O(n^n).

Comment: @ThomasJager Thank you very much for realising! I copypasted my fisrt version of the code when I still was thinking I didnt need to avoid buyers repeating selling points. 
I have now edited for the right one, so if every array represents a buyers and every position in the array a distance for him to reach to a selling point, I pretend to now where each one should go to have the fewer distance.
Thank you very much!